# После перехода на новый домен ссылки остаются с абсолютными путями на старый сайт

Tags: redirect, .htaccess

Добрый день.
Такая проблема, сайт переехал на новый домен, но в текстах до сих пор остаются ссылки с абсолютными путями на старый сайт.

Никак не могу настроить .htaccess, чтобы с любой ссылки http://OLD-SITE.ru/ переход был в рамках нового http://NEW-SITE.ru

Такие правила не работают:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-site\.ru
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ new-site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old-site\.ru
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ new-site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Скорее всего я что-то неправильно пишу.

Comment: `http://` перед new-site указывается?

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-site\.ru
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old-site\.ru
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Плюс обратите внимание на эту статью: **[Корректный переход со старого домена на новый](http://habrahabr.ru/post/168471/)**

Comment: Исправил - не работает.
Статью эту уже читал

Comment: @Romancho354, не работает вообще или для каких-то конкретных ссылок?

Comment: Не работает именно для ссылок, которые ссылаются на старый сайт.
Вопрос так и не решил. Есть подозрение, что проблема на хостинге.
Проблему решил автозаменой в базе данных :)